# Splitting a users Entry and store it in an array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to split a users entry by a space and store it an array. I am trying to print out all the elements in each index, but I am getting an error saying index out of bound.

For example, I want to print out `"Hello world"`, I am getting a out of bound exception :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = scan.next();
String[] result = command.split(" ");
System.out.print(result[0]);
System.out.print(result[1]);
```

Comment: Scan.next() only consumes one token. Use nextLine()

Answer (score 0):

From Javadoc:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

As [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens) wrote, the problem is that a space (" ") is a token terminator, and it means the scan.next() only gets the first word. If the delimiter was, say, a dash ("-") this would work with scan.next(). In any case, scan.nextLine() is how you want to read a line of text.

Answer (score 0):

scan.next() will only get the first "block" you input so it only reads "Hello", you should use scan.nextLine() and you would get the whole "Hello World".

However, the way you are printing the answer you would print "HelloWorld"